# XML attribute search Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

SO I am running a third party program that outputs in XML .... here is the XML section I am interested in:

```
<something>
    <process>
      <iteration number="0" value="186.88" delta="0.5" nu="0.5" rho="0.125" x="0.4375" max_f_grad="45.192" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
      <iteration number="1" value ="125.89" delta ="0.44955" nu ="0.46812" rho ="0.1217" x="0.39894" max_f_grad="4.5908" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
      <iteration number="2" value ="90.528" delta ="0.22576" nu ="0.48615" rho ="0.15828" x="0.44465" max_f_grad="2.8968" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
      <iteration number="3" value ="75.885" delta ="0.22523" nu ="0.49176" rho ="0.19133" x="0.44226" max_f_grad="2.8594" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
      <iteration number="4" value ="68.869" delta ="0.21915" nu ="0.49569" rho ="0.21463" x="0.43686" max_f_grad="2.8433" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
      <iteration number="5" value ="64.864" delta ="0.2238" nu ="0.49721" rho ="0.22948" x ="0.43071" max_f_grad="2.8375" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
...........
............
    </process>
<something>
```

Now I get the value of "iteration number" in a variable  say `it=200` in my python script and want to find the corresponding delta and value....How do I do this in `python` I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using xml.elementtree.Etree, you can get the value of any `value` or `delta` attribute with the following code:

```
values_list = []
deltas_list = []
for iteration in root.findall(".//process/iteration"):
    values_list.add(iteration.attrib["value"])
    deltas_list.add(iteration.attrib["delta"])
```

If you actually want to do something with the values you're getting from the `value` and `delta` attributes, just switch out the `print` statements for something that assigns those values to an object that'll persist outside the iterations.

This iterates through all the `<process>` elements in your root element `<something>`, and therein iterates through all `<iteration>` elements contained within each `<process>` element.

Edit: If I've misunderstood your question, and what you wanted was to save *only* the values of the `value` and `delta` attributes within an element where the value of the attribute `number` is `200`:

```
values = []
deltas = []
for two_hundred_iteration in root.findall(".//process/iteration[@number='200']"):
    values.append(two_hundred_iteration.attrib["value"])
    deltas.append(two_hundred_iteration.attrib["delta"])
```

Note that this syntax only works with ElementTree 1.3 or higher, so if you've got Python 2.7 or less, it won't work for you.

Comment: ok so if I want to save the `value` for `number=200` in a variable ... how do i do that?

Comment: If you want to do that, the easiest way would be to save it in a list. I'll modify the above code to do that.

Comment: argument for `iteration` needs to match an attribute name; e.g. "values" should be "value"

Comment: @jrennie Right you are! Thanks for the fix.

Comment: Well yes, the second solution is what I need ..... but the problem is that I get a weird error that `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`...pointing to the if condition .... so I am writing the structure of the XML file.... can you please write the code including the Etree setup : Here is the structure of the xml file:
All data encapsulated in `<info>` its child `<opt>` (1 of 6) (this is something in my que) its child `<process>` and all its children as `<iteration number= ` .....

Comment: @user3145076 Ah, I got something a little wrong in the documentation. One sec.

Answer (score 0):

How to print the "value" for the iteration element with number="200" using ElementTree:

```
for process in root.findall("process"):
  for iteration in process.findall("iteration"):
    if int(iteration["number"]) == 200:
      print iteration["value"]
```

Beware that ElementTree loads the XML into memory, so it's not ideal for very large (~gigabyte+) files.

Comment: I'm not sure the user necessarily wanted to filter for any particular iteration number. I'm not sure, though - the question is very unclear.

Comment: @furkle Between the question and the first comment on your answer, I think this is a pretty good answer to the question. But, it's better to let the OP decide/clarify.

Comment: Oh, it's a perfectly good answer, and likely an answer the OP was looking for. And I totally glazed over the `number=200` part, which definitely changes my view of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict)

```
>>> doc = xmltodict.parse("""
... <something>
...     <process>
...         <iteration number="0" value="186.88" delta="0.5" nu="0.5" rho="0.125" x="0.4375" max_f_grad="45.192" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
...         <iteration number="1" value ="125.89" delta ="0.44955" nu ="0.46812" rho ="0.1217" x="0.39894" max_f_grad="4.5908" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
...         <iteration number="2" value ="90.528" delta ="0.22576" nu ="0.48615" rho ="0.15828" x="0.44465" max_f_grad="2.8968" max_greyness_grad="0"/>
...     </process>
... <something>
... """)
>>> doc["something"]["process"]["iteration"]
... [OrderedDict([(u'@max_f_grad', u'45.192'), (u'@number', u'0'), (u'@value', u'186.88'), (u'@max_greyness_grad', u'0'), (u'@rho', u'0.125'), (u'@delta', u'0.5'), (u'@x', u'0.4375'), (u'@nu', u'0.5')]), OrderedDict([(u'@max_f_grad', u'4.5908'), (u'@number', u'1'), (u'@value', u'125.89'), (u'@max_greyness_grad', u'0'), (u'@rho', u'0.1217'), (u'@delta', u'0.44955'), (u'@x', u'0.39894'), (u'@nu', u'0.46812')]), OrderedDict([(u'@max_f_grad', u'2.8968'), (u'@number', u'2'), (u'@value', u'90.528'), (u'@max_greyness_grad', u'0'), (u'@rho', u'0.15828'), (u'@delta', u'0.22576'), (u'@x', u'0.44465'), (u'@nu', u'0.48615')])]
```

With that data you can look better.